# How to say 'what's the difference between' in Cantonese?

Tags: cantonese

I'm just wondering how to say 'what's the difference between X and X?' in Cantonese

Any help (Jyutping or characters!) would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> what's the difference between X and Y

Cantonese:

> "(X) 同 (Y) 有乜嘢唔同" [*(X) tung4 (Y) jau5 me1 je5 m4 tung4*]
>
> "(X) 同 (Y) 有乜嘢分別" [*(X) tung4 (Y) jau5 me1 je5 fan1 bit6*]

Mandarin:

> "(X) 跟 (Y) 有甚麼不同" [*(X) gen1 (Y) you3 shen2 me5 bu4 tong2*]
>
> "(X) 跟 (Y) 有甚麼分別" [*(X) gen1 (Y) you3 shen2 me5 fen1 bie2*]

Comment: I think the proper pronunciation of 乜嘢 is "mat1 je5", though when it spoken quickly it sounds like "me1 je5".